# Force Hardware Acceleration on HTML5 video tag (per html or js)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a website in which I have to play videos synchronically. These videos sometimes play 100ms or so asynchronically, which is too much.

On chrome you can set the flag "Override software rendering list", which results in near perfect synchron videos.

"Override software rendering list" will allowed Chrome to use the system's graphics card even when it is theoretically not allowed to do so.

Is there any way to force/allow Chrome to use the GPU in html or javascript? Can I set the Chrome flag per html or javascript?